# подскажите в чем проблема с перегрузкой оператора вывода из файла >>(фин)

Tags: c++, файлы, классы, указатели, операторы

```
#pragma once
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"
#include "fstream"
class product
{
private:
char* Name;
double Kkal;
double Belok;
double Yglevod;
double Gur;
public:
product()
{
    Kkal = Belok = Yglevod = Gur = 0;
    Name= "";
}
product(double bel, double ygl, double gur, char* name)
{
Belok= bel;
Yglevod= ygl;
Gur= gur;
Kkal= (bel*4)+(ygl*4)+(gur*9);
Name= name;
}

friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const product p1)
{
os<<p1.Name<<p1.Belok<<" белка, "<<p1.Gur<<" жира, "<<p1.Yglevod<<"     углеводов, "<<p1.Kkal<<"ккал ";
    return os;
}
friend  std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream& fout, const product& p1)
{
fout.open("product.txt",std::ios::app);
  fout << p1.Name <<std::endl;
  fout << p1.Belok <<  ' ' << p1.Gur <<  ' '  << p1.Yglevod << ' ' <<          p1.Kkal<< std::endl;
      return fout;
}   
friend std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream& fin, product& p1) 
{
    fin.getline(p1.Name, 30);
    fin >> p1.Belok;
    fin >> p1.Gur; 
    fin >> p1.Yglevod;
    (fin >> p1.Kkal).get();
    return fin;
}
product operator+(const product& a) const
{
    product summa;
    summa.Belok= Belok+a.Belok;
    summa.Gur= Gur+a.Gur;
    summa.Yglevod= Yglevod+a.Yglevod;
    summa.Kkal= Kkal+a.Kkal;
    return summa;
}

};
```

---

```
friend std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream& fin, product& p1)
```

некорректно работает

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо выделить память куда вы собираетесь считать символьное значение для поля `Name`.

```
fin.getline(p1.Name, 30);
```

У вас поле `Name` объявлено как указатель, а не как массив.

Если вы объявите это поля, как имеющее тип `std::string`, то определение класса сильно облегчится.

```
class product
{
private:
     std::string Name;
    //...
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, а как тогда в конструкторах его заполнить? через strcpy()?

Comment: @Макс Если использовать класс std::string, то просто присвоить строку.

Comment: со стринг можно будет вместо 
    fin.getline(p1.Name, 30);
сделать 
    fin>>p1.Name;
?? или вывести